# STRING ID - allelic differences and splice variants

Tags: bioinformatics

[STRING](http://string-db.org) has protein (amino acid sequences) mapped to a single gene ID.
I have these doubts with respect to STRING ID.
I find that

> 1.All alleles of a single gene share the same STRING ID and
>
> 2.Especially in Eukaryotes, splice variants of the single gene(which might translate to different proteins) share the same STRING ID.

Does STRING take into account these two things like UniProt and have different IDs based on allelic differences and splice variants?If so,how?

Comment: At this moment the STRING database is not accessible. Can you give an example?

Comment: Rv`xxxx` is a gene id.

Comment: STRING uses only gene ID to map protein sequences

Comment: STRING is now working.Another example STRING ID:4932.Q0010 (Saccharomyces cerevisiae) AA sequence:MYYIMFLYNMLLIIILIFYSIVGVPIIIFNNNYYWDPDIFLFIIYYFIKFIIIFNLYLYYMINYIVYTPSGSPPGRGTYI LLYNMLYSYNMFIDYVMKFITCVTYMYLMFWLLSPTPSPYYVSEVPVS

Comment: please don't use (non-biological) acronyms such as w.r.t - it makes things unnecessarily hard to read (http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/104/use-of-abbreviations-and-acronyms-in-answers)

Comment: okay changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STRING does not distinguish between different products of the same gene. E.g. for human, the protein identifier you see (`ENSP...`) corresponds to the longest splice form for each gene (`ENSG...`). Therefore, STRING won't help you if you need to distinguish between splice forms.

Splice forms are merged because for most sources of evidence, there is little data for the interactions of individual splice forms.

Comment: What about allelic differences?

Comment: we also don't distinguish alleles at all, we don't even retrieve them from Ensembl